# Appending the content of a file to files in another directory tree

Tags: find

I want to append the content of a file in my current directory to all the files in another directory recursively (so I need to append the content of that file to the files in the subdirectories too). So I tried to use find this way:

```
find dir -type f -exec cat toAppend >> {} \;
```

But it does not work as it seems to do nothing.
What I'm doing wrong?

PS: I've solved the problem by doing

```
for i in `find dir -type f`
do
    cat toAppend >> $i
done
```

But I still cannot understand why my find invocation is wrong.

Comment: [Redirection or pipe inside `find -exec`](https://superuser.com/a/1411724/432690). Your solution is the [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).